# ASP.NET - define a variable in an ASP page, then use it for a web control attribute's value

Tags: asp.net, regex

Is it possible in an ASP page to define a variable, then use that variable for a web control's attribute value?

I'm trying to add validation controls to my ASP.NET page, and one of them is a regex control. The expression I want will check that a field only contains numbers, spaces, plus sign and round brackets. (for phone numbers) Now round brackets are a special character that can't be escaped with a slash (as far as I can tell), so what I did was use Regex.Escape() to construct my regular expression, which I stored as a string variable. I now want to use that variable as the value for the regex validation control's expression attribute. Is this possible? If not, how can I achieve the validation I want?

EDIT1: So, in the  tag of my ASP page I have this:

```
<% string PhoneNumber = "[^0-9 |^" + Regex.Escape("(") + " |^" + Regex.Escape(" "); %>
```

Then further down I have this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MobilePhoneValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MobilePhone" ErrorMessage="Mobile phone number must only contain numbers." ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression=PhoneNumber></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I'm pretty sure that using ValidationExpression="PhoneNumber" will use the actual string PhoneNumber and not look up my variable. Though to be honest, I haven't actually tried that.

Comment: Please show us your code and where you are stuck. We'll sort it out from there.

Comment: Added my code, except the ASP web control code isn't showing up, I'll see if I can figure out why.

Comment: Just do it in the code-behind file and not the markup code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you spcified a string in markup rather than code behind, but anyway.

Assigning this string to your validator looks like this then:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MobilePhoneValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MobilePhone" ErrorMessage="Mobile phone number must only contain numbers." ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<% string PhoneNumber = "[^0-9 |^" + Regex.Escape("(") + " |^" + Regex.Escape(" "); 
   MobilePhoneValidator.ValidationExpression = PhoneNumber; %>
```

Or you could just define it in your code file, rather then markup.

Comment: In the code I have a Variables class file which is where I put all the variables I want to reuse, like this one. I wasn't sure if I could access variables from files other than the one directly attached to the current page. If I can, then that would be amazing and I'd just use the variable I defined in my Variables class.

With that markup code, I can define the variable at the start, and then access it in markup code further down, right? I'll be using this regex for 3 different fields, and it seems redundant to define the variable 3 times.

Comment: So basically what I've got from this is that to use variables with ASP controls, I have to make a little code section where I change the value of the control's attribute, correct? I can't just write a control and put a variable into it.

Comment: Just do it in code behind. Don't mix markup and logic.

Comment: Yes, but they are available in the code behind as well to be manipulated and dealt with. You should really read up on the basics of asp.net webforms.